# Creating a new branch using Github Mac Application

Tags: macos, github, branch

When I create a new branch using the Github Mac App, that branch does not show up on the Github website.  Also the other way around is the same, when I create a new branch using the website, that branch does not show up on the app.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

edit: I believe it is because nothing had been committed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push the local branch to your repo to have it appear on Github.com. You can do this by clicking the `Publish` button next to the branch on the Branches view, or the `Publish Branch` button in the window's title bar.

You have to pull the remote branch from Github.com to have it appear locally. I believe the only way to do that from the Github for Mac client is to use the `Sync` button.